# Styling JSF button

Tags: css, jsf

I have the following button

```
<h:commandButton id="user" action="user?faces-redirect=true" styleClass="rightlogo"/>
```

and in my css the class

```
.rightlogo{
margin: 5px;
padding: 10px 5px 5px 5px; 
border: 0px;
}
```

I want to style it using CSS so that on click, there won't be any border. Currently there is a blue border (like the one from a href).

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using `.rightlogo:focus{`

**CSS**

```
 .rightlogo:focus{
outline:none;
border:none;
}
```

**REMEMBER**: if you are giving `:hover`,then `:focus` must come after `:hover` inorder for `:focus` to work